# transparent activity make other activities background black

Tags: android

I have a pretty complex main activity that has a button at the bottom that slide up new profile activity. Profile activity has its height set to 70% of screen and a transparent background trough theme.

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/ProfileDialogAnimation</item>

</style>
```

If I don’t open profile activity and I navigate through my application everything is working as expected, except when I come back and open profile activity it’s not transparent but have a background (image) the same as other activities. 
Second test (after force stopping application trough application manager, if I just close application behavior is the same).

If I open profile activity right away the transparency is working as it should, but when I open another activity with image for background, instead of image I see black background. If the activity has a solid color background it’s displayed correctly.

If I remove transparency stuff from my custom theme (those two lines)

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

Everything is working ok. (Obviously profile activity is not see trough)
So basically if I navigate to activity with transparent background, set trough theme, all other activities with image for background are black.

I know it’s a long shot thinking you could help me with so little data, but keeping my fingers crossed.

Comment: not sure if it would work for you , but in ProfileActivity only you should implement the transparent background stuff.. not in the common theme..

Comment: Only the ProfileActivity has theme set to Theme.Transparent, other activities ether don't have a theme or have a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot's of testing i change the background image format form png to jpeg and for now everything seems to working as it should.